# VS Code "Identifier under caret" background highlight color

Tags: visual-studio-code, color-scheme, vs-color-theme-editor

How to change "Identifier under caret" background highlight color ?

Tried:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": { 
    "editor.findMatchBackground": "#000000",
    "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#000000",
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#000000",
    "editor.wordHighlightStrongBackground": "#000000",
    "editor.hoverHighlightBackground": "#000000",
}
```

No result.

[image: Identifier under caret]

Comment: Is "year" selected in your example - it appears so since the first year is colored as well.  Try     "editor.selectionBackground": "#f00",  as the color of the selected item under the cursor.  "editor.findMatchBackground": "#0000", will work on the first "year" in your example.

Comment: Mark, thanks for answer but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After try many times:

```
"editor.wordHighlightTextBackground": "#ff0000"
```